# how to add item to array by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I usually add item to array in PHP by

```
$a = array();
$a['key'] = 'value';
```

But it give me a E_NOTICE warning of undefined index.

How to add item to array by Key correctly.

Comment: Is that the only code in the script?

Comment: I doubt that snip of code is the caused of `E_NOTICE`

Comment: You need to post more code, there's obviously nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

First off, read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). It explains everything about arrays.

Secondly, your code looks fine. Are you sure you are declaring your array properly? Post your exact code - obsfusticating your code by changing names and values does not help - especially since it can easily cover up the error.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't give any warning at all, are you sure the problem isn't with `value`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the value to the array by key by doing:

```
$a = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);
```

etc etc. This is really only viable if you are creating an array with all the keys known a head of time. You could create an empty array and fill it in with values later on if you want to be super complete and do not have the values a head of time like so:

```
$a = array(
    'key' => '',
    'key2' => ''
);

$a['key']  = 'value';
$a['key2'] = 'value2';
```

Comment: I don't have prior key name for the array.